# Tag Synonim / Tag Merge: [book] --> [books]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Another two dupe tags caught my eye today: [book](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) and [books](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) - the first only has one question.

PS: I am starting to think that it would be more productive to just reuse the same question to signal any clone we may find (at last untill we hit 1250 rep and can start [to propose synonyms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've merged book into books. You can also ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint) and I'll do the merge.

Comment: Leaved a message on the chat... but correct me if I'm mistaken.. there *isn't* an actual "ping/pm user" function right? or does the @UserName work in the chat?

Comment: It should notify me when you use "@KitMenke" .. I think my notifications have been weird since I check SharePoint.SE on multiple computers.